# Custom .desktop file, trying to launch a .sh

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

(I was told by AskUbuntu to post my question here)

I have installed SQL Developer, which I need to execute by running 
`sudo /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh` 

I made a custom .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SQLDeveloper
Comment=SQL Developer
Exec=sudo /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
Icon=/home/floris/Downloads/icon.png
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Databases
```

Unfortunately, when I run this launcher - nothing happens. I have also tried using gksudo -k -u root  but unsuccessful as well.

Anyone that can help me out?
It's also worth mentioning that I am running Elementary OS Freya.

Thank you, in advance.

EDIT: If I right click on the launcher and select 'Run as root' the application works fine though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need root privileges, try adding quotes and removing `sudo`, like:

```
Exec="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh"
```

However, if you need to run it in sudo, I don't know how to achieve that. Maybe create another script, to run your script, or something like that, idk.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting "sudo" in line:

> Exec=sudo /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately nothing changes!